# Clicking radio button doesn't show other div

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-show

I'm new to bootstrap and angularjs and I'm trying to create something rather simple, but as it seems there's some kind of problem I can't see.

I want to show a div if the value of the radio equals true and hide it if the value of the radio is false. This is the code I have so far - I looked into examples in the internet, they all seem to do the same like I do.

I haven't defined any controllers so far, just this html file ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qcwh7k8x/)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form>
            <div class="row">
                ...
            </div>

            ...

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label>Wunschpartner</label>
                </div>

                <div  class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                        <label class="btn btn-default active">
                            <input type="radio" name="preferredDealer" value="false" ng-model="preferredDealer" data-ng-value="false" checked> Nein
                        </label>

                        <label class="btn btn-default">
                            <input type="radio" name="preferredDealer" value="true" ng-model="preferredDealer" data-ng-value="true"> Ja
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            Test: {{hasOne}} <!-- Displays no value at all -->
            <div class="row" ng-show="preferredDealer">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label for="text">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Garage Max Muster">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label for="text">PLZ</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="1234">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label for="text">Ort</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Musterhausen">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Interesting enough, if I replace the radios with a text field having `ng-model="preferredDealer"` and type `true` into it, it'll display the div - as soon as I change it to something other than true, it'll hide.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It seems correct, any errors in console ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in Bootstrap 3:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4516

using data-toggle prevents the model to be updated.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the information. What a coincidence, first thing I want to try is buggy, off to a great start :O

Answer (score 1):

```
<body ng-app>
    <div class="container">
    <form> 
      <label>Wunschpartner</label>
       <label class="btn btn-default">
                            <input type="radio" name="preferredDealer" value="false" ng-model="preferredDealer" > Nein</label>


     <label class="btn btn-default">
                            <input type="radio" name="preferredDealer" value="true" ng-model="preferredDealer" > Ja</label>


    </form>

            Test<!-- Displays no value at all -->
            <div class="row" ng-show="preferredDealer">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label for="text">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Garage Max Muster">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label for="text">PLZ</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="1234">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label for="text">Ort</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Musterhausen">
                </div>
            </div>



    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the working version :) I decided to use a single checkbox instead since it looks nicer, having the radio dot in the box looks strange :)